# LaTeX long subequation

Tags: equations, conversion

I have converted Microsoft Office equations to LaTeX. The equations are pretty long, and they are seen on the screen. I have used split, gather, and similar approaches, but I could not do it. Is there a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}

  \begin{split}
    U_{D}(x, y, z, t)=&\left(\sin \left(k_{x} x\right) \sin \left(k_{y} y\right) \sin \left(k_{z} z\right)\right.\\
    &+\cos \left(k_{x} x\right) \sin \left(k_{y} y\right) \sin \left(k_{z} z\right)+\sin \left(k_{x} x\right) \cos \left(k_{y} y\right) \sin \left(k_{z} z\right) \\
    &\left.+\sin \left(k_{x} x\right) \sin \left(k_{y} y\right) \cos \left(k_{z} z\right)\right)^{2}-t^{2} \\
  \end{split}

  \begin{split}
    U_{G}(x, y, z, t)=&\left(\cos \left(k_{x} x\right) \sin \left(k_{y} y\right)+\cos \left(k_{y} y\right) \sin \left(k_{z} z\right)+\cos \left(k_{z} z\right) \sin \left(k_{x} x\right)\right)^{2}-t^{2} \\
  \end{split}

  \begin{split}
    U_{I-W P}(x, y, z, t)=& 2\left(\cos \left(k_{x} x\right) \cos \left(k_{y} y\right)+\cos \left(k_{y} y\right) \cos \left(k_{z} z\right)+\cos \left(k_{z} z\right) \cos \left(k_{x} x\right)\right.\\
    &\left.-\left(\cos \left(2 k_{x} x\right)+\cos \left(2 k_{y} y\right)+\cos \left(2 k_{y} y\right)\right)\right)^{2}-t^{2} \\
  \end{split}

\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! First you need to remove all empty lines in your equations code. Then try reformat your equations, for example break it into more lines.

Comment: OT, but is that last group (before the final `-t^2`) supposed to be `\cos(2k_x x) +\cos(2k_y y) + \cos(2k_z z)` -- that is, with `z` in the third term?

Comment: It's not mentioned in any of the answers (and in fact is irrelevant there), but you want to be aware that no environment intended for multiple lines (like `split`) should be used for only a single line.  It affects the positioning and especially the way the vertical spacing is handled.

Comment: Thank you so much :). It worked very well.

Comment: You receive three answer, so now is time to accept one of them (by clicking on the check mark at the top left side of answer), which solve (according to your opinion) your problem on the best way. Also, your thankfulness you can express by up-voting of answers :-)

Answer (score 8):

I'd first get rid of all `\left` and `\right` commands that do nothing useful and something harmful.

Next I'd use more lines even if some could fit in a merged line.

Most important: blank lines inside `align` are not allowed and the final `\\` should be outside `split`. I added some vertical space to separate the various parts.

A final touch is the `\smash[b]{...}` so to get uniform line spacing after noting that the exponents don't clash with the line above them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
  U_{D}(x, y, z, t)&=
    \bigl(\sin (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z) \\
    &\qquad+\cos (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z) \\
    &\qquad+\sin (k_{x} x) \cos (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z) \\
    &\qquad+\sin (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \cos (k_{z} z)
     \smash[t]{\bigr)^{2}}-t^{2}
  \end{split}
\\[1ex]
  \begin{split}
  U_{G}(x, y, z, t)&=
    \bigl(\cos (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \\
    &\qquad+\cos (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z) \\
    &\qquad+\cos (k_{z} z) \sin (k_{x} x)
     \smash[t]{\bigr)^{2}}-t^{2}
  \end{split}
\\[2ex]
  \begin{split}
  U_{I-W P}(x, y, z, t)&=
    2\bigl(\cos (k_{x} x) \cos (k_{y} y) \\
    &\qquad+\cos (k_{y} y) \cos (k_{z} z) \\
    &\qquad+\cos (k_{z} z) \cos (k_{x} x)\\
    &\qquad-(\cos (2 k_{x} x)+\cos (2 k_{y} y)+\cos (2 k_{y} y))
     \smash[t]{\bigr)^{2}}-t^{2}
  \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). It worked very well.

Answer (score 3):

After rid of all unnecessary `\left(` and `\right)`, replaced outer parenthesis with square brackets, use for the `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` sizes, in each split breake long equation line into two parts and put the last line terminations after `\end}split}, the result of MWE compilation is:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
U_{D}(x, y, z, t) ={}
    & \bigl[\sin (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z) \\
    & + cos (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z)\\
    & + \sin (k_{x} x) \cos (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z) \\
    &+ \sin (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \cos (k_{z} z)\bigr]^{2}-t^{2}
  \end{split} \\
%
  \begin{split}
U_{G}(x, y, z, t) ={}
    & \bigl[\cos (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y)+\cos (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z)  \\
    & + \cos (k_{z} z) \sin (k_{x} x)\bigr]^{2}-t^{2}
  \end{split} \\
%
  \begin{split}
U_{I-W P}(x, y, z, t)= {}
    & 2\bigl[\cos (k_{x} x) \cos (k_{y} y)+\cos (k_{y} y) \cos (k_{z} z)  \\
    & + \cos (k_{z} z) \cos (k_{x} x)   \\
    & - \cos (2 k_{x} x)+\cos (2 k_{y} y)+\cos (2 k_{y} y)\bigr]^{2}-t^{2}
  \end{split}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). It worked very well.

Answer (score 3):

In the following answer, the focus of the formatting work is on balancing the "outer" parentheses (which I've converted to curly braces) across the three subequations. This is achieved by placing `aligned` environments inside the `split` environments. Further care is taken to keep the distances between each row the same within each subequation, with the help of `\smash[b]` and `\smash[t]` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for align, split, and aligned environments

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  \begin{split}
    U_{D}(x, y, z, t)
    &=\phantom{2}\smash[b]{\bigl\{ }
      \begin{aligned}[t]
      & \sin (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z)\\
      &+\cos (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z)\\
      &+\sin (k_{x} x) \cos (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z) \\
      &+\sin (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y) \cos (k_{z} z)
      \smash[t]{\bigr\}^{2}} -t^{2} 
      \end{aligned}
  \end{split} \\[\jot]
  \begin{split}
    U_{G}(x, y, z, t)
    &=\phantom{2}\smash[b]{\bigl\{ }
      \begin{aligned}[t]
      & \cos (k_{x} x) \sin (k_{y} y)\\
      &+\cos (k_{y} y) \sin (k_{z} z)\\
      &+\cos (k_{z} z) \sin (k_{x} x)
      \smash[t]{\bigr\}^{2}} -t^{2} 
      \end{aligned}
  \end{split}  \\[\jot]
  \begin{split}
    U_{I-\mathit{W P}}(x, y, z, t)
    &=2\smash[b]{\bigl\{ }
      \begin{aligned}[t]
      & \cos (k_{x} x) \cos (k_{y} y)\\
      &+\cos (k_{y} y) \cos (k_{z} z)\\
      &+\cos (k_{z} z) \cos (k_{x} x)\\ 
      &-[\cos(2 k_{x} x)+\cos(2 k_{y} y)+\cos(2 k_{z} z)] 
      \smash[t]{\bigr\}^{2}} -t^{2} 
      \end{aligned}
  \end{split}  
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :). It worked very well.

Comment: @MirhanÖzdemir - You're most welcome.